# Creating a new array that ignores NaN entries

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nan

I have the following array with some sequence of `NaN` entries:

```
A = [..., 14, 19, 32, 41, NaN, NaN, NaN, 4, NaN, 51, 62, 74, 58, ...]
```

In a loop, I want to go through the array and when I find the first `NaN`, I want to construct another array `B` where I use the 4 preceding values and the first 4 non-`NaN` values that comes after the first `NaN` I find. So my `B` should look like this:

```
B = [14, 19, 32, 41, 4, 51, 62, 74, 58]
```

Obviously I can't use `B = A(~isnan(A))` because this will just create an A but without the `NaN`'s which I don't want.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: So, you basically describe a loop that uses the function you also mention. Any reason why you haven't given it a go? Does "neat" mean "non-loopy" in here? Note that since ~2007 there is no reason to avoid loops in MATLAB

Comment: @AnderBiguri - I have given many for loops a go but I can't get what I want. Stackoverflow is always a very last resort for me. I don't really understand what you mean in your first sentence. I don't have a problem finding the first NaN, second etc in a for loop what troubles me is how to extract only the non-NaN's that come after the first.

Comment: Sure, its good you tried stuff. But right now it feels like a code request, so it would be much easier to help you with code _you already have_ rather than writing code for you. My first sentence meant that the solution that comes to mind seems to just use the things you described, so you have the tools to write it. You know how to detect if a number in a loop is NaN, and then I assume you know how to index the previous numbers from that, and also you know how to index the posterior numbers of that (without nans). Can you show an example of your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` to get the first `NaN`, and use this to get the last or first 4 elements from the non-NaN elements before and after respectively:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 14, 19, 32, 41, NaN, NaN, NaN, 4, NaN, 51, 62, 74, 58, 4, 5, 6];

idxNaN = find( isnan(A), 1 );
idxOK = ~isnan(A);

B = A( [ find(idxOK(1:idxNaN-1), 4, 'last'), idxNaN+find(idxOK(idxNaN+1:end), 4) ] );

B =
    14    19    32    41     4    51    62    74
```

One nice thing here is that `find` will only return *up to* 4 elements (or however many you request), so you won't get an error if there are fewer available before/after the `NaN`. This code does assume there's at least one `NaN` - you could check whether `idxNaN` is empty to make this more robust.